# Eclipse: regain content assist for argument names

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

Eclipse has great content assist, e.g. for argument names (search for "Content assist can insert" in the following page):
http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html

But sometimes the nice "tabbing through arguments"-thing disappears (e.g. if I accidentally deleted a comma) and I have to use the arrow-keys to edit the next argument.

Is there a way to re-enable the mode where the arguments are outlined/framed and I can tab through them?

The only thing I found out is that I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> if the cursor is in front of a comma where the argument is missing to get a tool-tip showing the parameter list. But that does not give me back the nice tabbing feature.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean, I personally workaround this by either selecting the proposed arguments and edit then the references with my ones or by doing it again by Ctrl+Space after the dot and restart the on-the-fly content assist.